# Design DFA to check even number of 1s using 2 states.

Tags: computer-science, automata

The alphabet is {0,1}. Zero 1s in the string should be rejected. This can be done easily using 3 states. Can this be done usinng 2 states?

Comment: You need a start state and a state that says there are an odd number of $1$s. Since you are rejecting zero $1$s, the start state cannot correspond to the end state so you need at least $3$ states.

Answer (score 1):

How about $s_0\rightarrow_0 s_0$, $s_0\rightarrow_1 s_1$, and $s_1\rightarrow_{0,1} s_1$ with start state $s_0$ and end state $s_1$.

Ahh, okay. Sorry for misunderstanding. An even number of 1's. Then the automaton looks as follows:

$s_0\rightarrow_0 s_0$, $s_0\rightarrow_1 s_1$, $s_1\rightarrow_0 s_1$, and $s_1\rightarrow_{1} s_0$, where $s_0$ is the starting and ending state.

Comment: In the title the OP requires also an even number of 1s, not just a non-zero number.

Comment: "Zero 1s in the string should be rejected". This will accept 0.